# GLib.Settings.changed event not firing

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome, glib, vala

I'm trying to write an application in Vala, and have looked up in the Vala documentation how to work with GLib.Settings (dconf). Getting and setting values works. However, when I try to detect changes to the schema or a specific key using the `changed` event, the event simply does not fire.

Example: http://pastebin.com/dGuP9GyX

The changed event will never fire for some reason. The `bind ()` method does not work either (only in one direction).

### Forget the example below... It actually does work when you add \n, for some reason...

<s>Here's a small example to illustrate. Compile with the following command; `valac --pkg gio-2.0 --pkg gtk+-3.0 main.vala`</s>

```
int main (string[] args)
{
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    GLib.Settings settings = new GLib.Settings ("org.pantheon.terminal.settings");
    settings.changed["allow-bold"].connect (somethingChanged);

    Gtk.main ();

    return 0;
}

void somethingChanged ()
{
    stdout.printf ("Something changed");
}
```

When running this small example, in my case anyway, the program will just keep running. No matter how many settings I change in the specified dconf schema, it will not output anything.

Hoping someone can help me get past this barrier.

```
robin@RobinJ:~$ valac --version
Vala 0.20.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here isn't Vala or Glib, but how standard out works.  A printf will print nothing to the screen unless there's a newline character in there.

Just change the printf line to:

```
stdout.printf ("Something changed\n");
```

And you should be good to go!

Comment: Someone on IRC found that out, too. So basically I'm stumped now. The example works, while my main application, which does things the same way, still doesn't >.<

Comment: Since you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: Same question, man. Only it would appear my initial example was not ideal.